# Handling uncatchable exceptions from chained queueable - finalizer hitting retry limit

Tags: apex, queueable-apex, transaction-finalizers

We have a need to process a number of records (several thousand) using methods from a third-party managed package, which also involves callouts.

We've achieved this by passing in the list of objects to a queuable, removing the first one from the list and processing it, then requeueing with the remaining list. So far so good. Example:

```
private Processor(List<Id> objectsToProcess)
{
    m_ObjectsToProcess = objectsToProcess;
}

private List<Id> m_objectsToProcess;

public void execute(System.QueueableContext context)
{
    Id currentRecord = m_ObjectsToProcess.remove(0);
 
    // do stuff with currentRecord
        
    if (m_ObjectsToProcess.size() > 0)
    {
        System.enqueueJob(new Processor(m_ObjectsToProcess);
    }
}
```

Recently however, we've observed that the managed package will, for some records, throw a FinalException (specifically, they're doing `ApexPages.addMessage` which blows up if the context isn't a VF page) which doesn't get caught. This means the process aborts because the queueing of the remaining list doesn't then run.

Having read recently about TransactionFinalizers, I've implemented this and initially it looked promising... my finalizer implementation could log the ID of the failing record, and then still queue up the remaining list of records.

However- I've since discovered that after 5 failures, I am hitting the finalizer limit of `Unable to enqueue AsyncApexJob for finalizer: Attached Queueable job has hit the maximum retry limit of 5`

At this point I'm not sure of the best approach.

Option 1 - ask the 3rd party vendor to add some context checking around their call to `ApexPages.addMessage` (not convinced this option will fly)

Option 2 - see if there's any way I can programmatically determine a "bad" record and skip it before the 3rd party package throws its error (I'm not sure what triggers the error so this might be tricky, but perhaps possible)

Option 3 - the magic simple solution I'm hoping someone here knows :D

Comment: The enqueueJob call allows you to set the chain length for queueable in the options object you can pass in the second argument.

Comment: You can try splitting the records into smaller batches and enqueuing separate jobs for each batch or chunk.